# How do you get results from within JavaScript's deep object?

Tags: javascript, function

expect result: ["human", "head", "eye"]

ex.

```
const data = {
  name: "human",
  children: [
    {
      name: "head",
      children: [
        {
          name: "eye"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "body",
      children: [
        {
          name: "arm"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
const keyword = "eye"
```

Using the above data and using `f`function to obtain result

```
expect_result = f(data)
```

What kind of function should I write?

Thanks.

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain I understand the selection criteria for your expected result.  Is it supposed to be an array of the `name`s for the parents of the object whose name matches `keyword`?  If so then presumably you'd be needing to pass `keyword` into the function as well as `data`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach by checking the property or the nested children for the wanted value. If found unshift the name to the result set.

```js
function getNames(object, value) {
    var names = [];
    [object].some(function iter(o) {
        if (o.name === value || (o.children || []).some(iter)) {
            names.unshift(o.name);
            return true;
        }
    });
    return names;
}

var data = { name: "human", children: [{ name: "head", children: [{ name: "eye" }] }, { name: "body", children: [{ name: "arm" }] }] };

console.log(getNames(data, 'eye'));
console.log(getNames(data, 'arm'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a recursive function

```
const getData = items => {
   let fields = [];

   for (const item of items) {
     if (item.name) {
       fields.push(item.name);
     }

      if (Array.isArray(item.children)) {
        fields.push(...getData(item.children));  
      }
   }

   return fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = []   // This is outside the function since it get updated

function f(data) {
result.push(data.name);    // Add the only name to the Array

if (data.children) {   // just checking to see if object contains key children (staying safe)

for (var i = 0; i < data.children.length; i++) {  // we are only looping through the children

   f(data.children[i]);   // Call this particular function to do the same thing again

 }

}
}
```

Basically this function set the name. Then loop through the no of children and then calls a function to set the name of that child and then loop through its children too. Which happen to be a repercussive function till it finishes in order, all of them

Comment: It would be better if you add an explanation to why your code works.